# Where can I find documentation on all Opa directives?

Tags: opa

Looking for docs explaining directives such as `@publish`, which is mentioned in the "[Hello Chat](http://opalang.org/resources/book/index.html#_hello_chat)" example.

Answer (score 2):

http://opalang.org/resources/book/index.html#directives

Comment: Do you know where the target of the link went to? I know that the Manual has moved, but it has no "directives" section.

Comment: It's been a loong while I don't use Opa :/